# Troubles with ruby update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encountered some errors with my redmine installation.
I tried to update ruby and gems, but I'm not finding out a solution.

When I start the server, I got this answer :

```
:/usr/share/redmine# rails server
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

So I tried to update it but I'm still stuck with it :

```
 gem update --system
Installing RubyGems 3.2.16
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:43:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gem::BasicSpecification (NameError)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rubygems-update-3.2.16/lib/rubygems.rb:1348:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rubygems-update-3.2.16/lib/rubygems.rb:1348:in `<top (required)>'
        from setup.rb:23:in `require'
        from setup.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: And you've tried to simply run `gem update bundler` ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, but same at the end.

I finally "solved" the trouble by updating everything (redmine, debian 9->10 etc...)
Not a real solution but it works fine now...